# WordPress pagination not working with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

When I set permalinks to 'Plain', everything works.
When permalink is set to /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/ and I go to for example on Page 2 in link it shows http://baselink/page/2 but still remains on the first page.

Here's my code for pagination:

```
$pages = paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, $request->get('paged')),
            'total' => $this->config['maxNumPages'],
            'type'  => 'array',
            'prev_next'   => true,
            'prev_text'    => __('« Prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
        )
    );
```

Comment: try to use :
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),